# How to add pagination to following

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to apply pagination successfully to the following code

**code1**: main controller, under which i have a function login_process checks if user who is logging is valid or not by true status and if he is valid then it is checked whether column 'status' in database is 1 or 0 , if it is 1 then he is admin and he will be login .

```
    public function login_process()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
        $data['users'] = array(
                            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),

                            'pass'=> $this->input->post('pass'),

                           );           

        $status= $this->insert_model->login_test($data);
        $st['ss']=$this->insert_model->stat($data); 
        //print "<pre>"; print_r($status); die();
        if($status == true )
        {
            if( $st['ss'] [0] ['status'] == 0)
            {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();

             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('user_view');
            }
             else
             {
                $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();               

            // print_r($aaa); die();
            //  $data['aa'] = "sd"; 

            //$data['books'] = $this->abc();
            $data['books'] = $this->insert_model->pagination();
             //print "<pre>";print_r($data);die();
             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);
             }
         }
        else
            {

             $this->load->view('header_view');
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('center_view_login');
            }

}
```

**code 2**: now next code is of my controller insert_controller code in which various functions are used firstly to check wheter user is valid or not and secondly to check status column from database and also pagination code and image fetch code.

```
 public function login_test($users)
    {
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            $uname = $user['fname'];
            $pass = $user['pass'];
        }
        $query = $this->db->where('fname',$uname)
                ->where('pass',$pass)
                ->get('register');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)    
        {
            return $query->result_array(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    public function stat($users)
    {           
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            $uname = $user['fname'];
            $pass = $user['pass'];
        }
        $s= $this->db->select('status')->where('fname',$uname)->where('pass',$pass)->get('register');
        if($s->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return $s->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }           
    }
    public function image_fetc()
    {
        $us=$this->session->userdata('username');
        $pass=$this->session->userdata('password');
        $images= $this->db->select('image')->where('fname',$us)->where('pass',$pass)->get('register');
        return $images->result_array();
    }   

public function pagination(){

        //$this->load->model('insert_model');
         //$data ['query'] = $this->insert_model->view_data(); 
        $this->load->library('table');

        // Load Pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $total_row = $this->db->count_all("register");
        // Config setup
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/welcome/login_process';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $kk=$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
        $rpp = $config['num_links'] = 5;

        // Initialize
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Query the database and get results
        // Here we add the limit and the offset
        // The second parameter is the limit, since we are showing
        // 10 per page, the limit should be 10

        if($this->uri->segment(3)){
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
            }
            else{
            $page = 1;
            }
        $offset = ($rpp*$page)-$rpp;
        $qry = $this->db->get('register',15, $offset);

        // Create custom headers
        $header = array('id','username','lastname','email' , 'password', 'image','status');
        // Set the headings
        $this->table->set_heading($header);
        // Load the view and send the results
       // print_r($offset);die();
     /*   if($offset == 0)
        {   

        return $data['books'];

        }
        else
        {
       //$data['books'] = $this->abc();
            $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();
        $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
         $this->load->view('navside_view');
           $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);
            }
       // print_r($data); die();

    }*/return $qry->result_array();

}}
```

**code3**: last code is the code of my admin_view in which i want to do paging successfully but it is not going properly so plz help me how to do my pagination properly with this whole code

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($books); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

plz help me where i am wrong and plz do the correctness